# Truffle cant find script file

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, nodejs

I am trying to execute a script in my truffle project. The script is located in the scripts folder. But whether I run the command from within the root of the project or inside the scripts folder, it cant seem to find my file NiftRouter01.sol which is located in another project. I am using command `truffle exec './deploy_pool.js' --network bscTestnet`

```
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\commands.bundled.js:455204
        throw new Error("Could not find artifacts for " + import_path + " from any sources");
        ^

Error: Could not find artifacts for ../../niftswap-periphery/build/contracts/NiftRouter01.json from any sources
    at Resolver.require (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\resolver\dist\lib\resolver.js:43:1)
    at D:\Blockchain\pancake\pancakeswap-core\scripts\deploy_pool.js:2:26
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:131:20)
    at Script.runInNewContext (vm.js:137:17)
    at Object.file (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\require\require.js:94:1)    
    at Object.exec (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\require\require.js:121:1)   
    at internal/util.js:297:30
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at bound exec (internal/util.js:296:12)
    at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\exec.js:88:1
Truffle v5.1.49 (core: 5.1.49)
Node v12.18.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing - from the script name, deleting node_modules folder and package.json and forcing npm cache clean. Also placed the script in an external folder.